# Xamarin getting data from TextView that is offscreen

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I want to add functionality in my app to save changes. All the fields that can be changed are in RecyclerView. Initially my idea was to gather data from all the TextView-s after the user finished with the changes. It turns out tough that I cannot(or at least I have no idea how to) access TextViews that are offscreen. Any idea how I can achive this functionality?

This is my vewholder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editRecipieNameTextField"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editRecipieQuantityTextField"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/editRecipieMeasurementDropDown"
        android:entries="@array/measurement_array"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:background="#34eb9e"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    />
    <Button
        android:text="X"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#169c5d"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/deleteRowButton" />
</GridLayout>
```

This is my adapter

```
using Android.Views;
using AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget;
using Recipy.DataLayer;
using Recipy.Enums;
using Recipy.Models;
using Recipy.ViewHolders;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Recipy.Adapters
{
    internal class RecipieEditAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        public List<RecipieIngredients> recipieIngredients = new List<RecipieIngredients>();

        public List<string> recipieIngredientsNames = new List<string>();
        public List<double> recipieIngredientsQuantity = new List<double>();
        public List<string> recipieIngredientsMeasurement = new List<string>();

        public static Database database;

        public static Database Database
        {
            get
            {
                database = new Database(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "RecipyDataBase.db"));
                return database;
            }
        }

        public RecipieEditAdapter(
            int recipieId)
        {
            recipieIngredients = Database.GetAllRecipieIngredients(recipieId);

            foreach (var ingredient in recipieIngredients)
            {
                recipieIngredientsNames
                    .Add(Database
                    .GetIngredientNameById(ingredient.IngredientId));

                recipieIngredientsQuantity
                    .Add(Database
                    .GetIngredientQuantityById(recipieId, ingredient.IngredientId));

                recipieIngredientsMeasurement
                    .Add(Database
                    .GetIngredientMeasurementById(recipieId, ingredient.IngredientId));

            }   
        }

        public override int ItemCount => recipieIngredientsNames.Count;

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            if (holder is RecipieEditIngridientsViewHolder recipiesViewHolder)
            {
                recipiesViewHolder.IngredientName.Text = recipieIngredientsNames[position];
                recipiesViewHolder.IngredientQuantity.Text = recipieIngredientsQuantity[position].ToString();
                string measurement = recipieIngredientsMeasurement[position];
                int measurementId = (int)(MeasurementEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MeasurementEnum), measurement);
                recipiesViewHolder.IngredientMeasurement.SetSelection(measurementId);
            }
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View recipieEditIngredientsView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.recipieEditIngredients_viewholder, parent, false);
            RecipieEditIngridientsViewHolder recipiesViewHolder = new RecipieEditIngridientsViewHolder(recipieEditIngredientsView);
            return recipiesViewHolder;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#34eb9e">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title_recipies_details"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
         />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/recipie_details_short_description_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/shortDescriptionTextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/shortDescriptionEditField" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recipieEditIngredients"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ingredientsTitle"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <GridLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:columnCount="2">
        <Button
            android:text="@string/recipie_confirm_changes_button_text"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/ingredientsTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recipieConfirmChangesButton"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />
        <Button
            android:text="@string/recipie_cancel_changes_button_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recipieCancelChangesButton"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"/>
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to get the text of the view with first getting all the recyclerview childs with _recipieEditRecyclerView.ChildCount and then to get the data one by one with for loop and ((TextView)_recipieEditRecyclerView.FindViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).ItemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.editRecipieNameTextField)).Text

Comment: This is the most common misconception/misunderstanding of how RecyclerView works - the views themselves don't really store/hold any value. RecyclerView only SHOWS its underlying data. While you can have TextField in RecyclerView, once you scroll it away without storing the value somewhere - it's lost. You need to change/update the underlying data.

Comment: That actually cleared my strategy and made me switch to TextWatchers and helping me manage the inputs at the time of entering the information. Thank you very much!